# .tmp file getting downloaded when opening my link after deploying on netlify

Tags: deployment, netlify, temp

I am deploying a basic yelpcamp site's frontend on netlify. I have included the redirects folder and manually uploaded my frontend folder on netlify. But after it gets deployed when I click on hosted URL it is not taking me to site but only a tmp file gets downloaded on my downloads. Their is no error message.
Tech stack I am using is EJS and JS on frontend with Node and Mongo for backend.Can anyone help me diagonose this behaviour and deploying my site. Thanks

The hosted link is "https://playful-manatee-914655.netlify.app", after clicking you should be able to see the issue. It just downloads a .tmp file of my project